# Query nested object mongoose

Tags: node.js, regex, mongoose

i am trying to reproduce the "like" behavior in mongoose by searching all elements where user name is something like "abcd..."
this function return abject that i feed db.find function with

```
const rgx = (pattern) => new RegExp(`.*${pattern}.*`);
const orFilter = [];
fields.forEach((field) => {
  if (field.includes('.')) {
    const [parent, child] = field.split('.');
    orFilter.push({
      [parent]: { [child]: { $regex: rgx(searchText), $options: 'i' } },
    });
  } else {
    orFilter.push({ [field]: { $regex: rgx(searchText), $options: 'i' } });
  }
});
return { $or: orFilter };
```

- entry 1: ['city','zipCode'] working ok
- entry 2 : ['city','zipCode','user.name'] does not work.

i have this message  *CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value
{ name: { '$regex': /.*abc.*/, '$options': 'i' } }
*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution to my probleme was found by using  aggregation visit
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/!
i tried to access a value stored in another table `user.name`